# how to set value to textarea in webbrowser c# app

Tags: c#, browser

I want to fill a textarea with c# webbrowser , but the textarea is created with "jhtmlarea.js".

This code does not work:

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["message"];
        if (textArea != null)
        {
            textArea.InnerText = "This is a test";
        }
```

How do I set the string to javascript editor like "jhtmlarea.js"?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Webbrowser-control contains a method called "InvokeScript". You can use it to invoke a piece of JavaScript in your document. Simply call

```
browser.InvokeScript("myFunction", new object[] { arg1, arg2,});
```

to invoke the function.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further reference.

Comment: i want to fill textbox on editor (see editor image in link : http://www.denizsoft.com/yashar/textarea.jpg)

any code not work

this editor use this : <script src="http://facenama.com/themes/basic/js/jHtmlArea.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("message");
 if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = "This is a test";
```